# can D6 be generated by one rotation and one reflection, or by two reflections?

Tags: group-theory

Can D6 be generated by one rotation and one reflection or by two reflections?

And am I correct in saying it is true that any choice of two reflections in the group D8 of symmetries of the square will generate
the whole group D8?

Comment: I believe this is false.  You need to choose two reflections that multiply to give you a rotation of "order 6."  Wouldn't it be possible to get instead a rotation of order 2 or 3?  That wouldn't give the whole group.

Comment: Wait, is your $D_6$ order 6 or 12?

Comment: For $D_8$ then, take my first comment and replace 6 by 4.  You could get a rotation of order 2 (so, 180 degrees), which won't generate the whole group.

Comment: It's D6 for sure